# Googl-sites images problem ( carousel ) slides , doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-sites

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRdV9.png)

I have a problem that when i copied the codes from visual studio to Google-sites website  the images don't show up, as you can see in the Pic below.

<

thank you

Comment: its because your code contains something like `src="a.png"` instead you have to upload the pictures to websites like *imgbb* and set image to URL like `src="https://url.image.png..."`

Comment: Share your code in visual studio here

Comment: <!-- one image code -->
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="1.png" alt="Student guide" style="width:100%;">

Comment: Last update ( I tried another URL from imgbb ) it worked at my computer but it didn't in the  phone.

Comment: please share the full code that has *URL* **Inside question & Not it comments**